# Linking OpenCV and FFMpeg to other software

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, linker

How can I install OpenCV and FFMpeg to only one place in the filesystem and link all the other software, which need them, to those installations while compiling?

So far, I always had to build OpenCV and FFMpeg again to satisfy the dependencies of the software since I don't know how to link them externally.

For example, I want to make and install OpenCV only in my `/usr/local` directory and point other dependent software to this location.

Comment: typically libraries have some install routine (e.g. `make install`) that does exactly that: installs the library to /usr/local/lib (or similar) and/or creates symbolic links. After that you only have to add that directory to your project settings (which is typically already added by default).

Comment: have a look at: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html